# Nuxt 3 App Freezes Windows on 429 Response from Server - Need Help Resolving

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, fetch-api, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm encountering a critical issue with my Nuxt 3 application that has been causing my Windows environment to freeze whenever the server responds with a 429 status code. To elaborate, when the server returns a 429 (Too Many Requests) response, the entire window becomes unresponsive, and I have to force-close it. Subsequently, reopening a new tab seems to be the only way to resume normal functioning.

Here are some additional details about my setup:

Nuxt 3 version: ^3.9.1
Server response code causing the issue: 429 (Too Many Requests)

I've been able to replicate this bug in both windows and macos, also it happens in any browser.

I have this Middleware for auth and this other function is my error handler

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(to => {
   const codeKey: string = to.query.codeKey?.toString().trim() ?? ''
   const is_codekey_in_url: boolean = codeKey !== ''

   const store_user = useStoreUser(useNuxtApp().$pinia)
   const is_codekey_not_setted: boolean = store_user.auth_header.codeKey === ''
   const is_not_logging_in: boolean = to.path !== '/login'

   if (is_codekey_in_url) {
      const is_impersonate: boolean = Boolean(to.query.impersonate)
      store_user.setCodekey(codeKey, is_impersonate)
      return navigateTo(to.path)
   } else if (is_codekey_not_setted && is_not_logging_in) {
      return store_user.navigateLogin()
   }
})
```

```
function handleRequestError(
      error: Error | unknown,
      message: string,
      is_toast_enabled: boolean = true,
   ): void {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
         if ('statusCode' in error) {
            if (error.statusCode !== 401) {
               if (is_toast_enabled) {
                  toast.add({
                     detail: `${message} Try again or contact support.`,
                     life: 3000,
                     severity: 'error',
                     summary: 'Error',
                  })
               } else {
                  console.log('error', error, ' ', message)
               }
            } else {
               store_user.clearCodekey()
               if (is_toast_enabled) {
                  toast.add({
                     detail: 'Autentication failed. Redirecting to login...',
                     life: 3000,
                     severity: 'error',
                     summary: 'Error',
                  })
                  setTimeout(() => store_user.navigateLogin(), 4000)
               } else {
                  store_user.navigateLogin()
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: Probably an infinite loop.

Comment: Yup. That was the problem. I was looking in the wrong places. Thank you!!